# what is and how can i stop the constant "canceling..." in the compositer?

Tags: compositing-nodes

At the moment I'm working on a project and I was using the compositor. I don't know what started it, but at the top of my screen, there is a bar that constantly says "canceling"[image]

also, my render layer node outputs are flickering

[image]

I'm making a graphics design thing with animation nodes, that's what you can see in the compositor. I 'm trying to put a vintage noise over it that's what you can see playing in the top.

[image]

and next to that my compositor is very very slow.

I have tried a lot of stuff to make it go away. I have restarted blender, I have reinstalled blender and I have tried to remake my whole node setup. but nothing works. the only way to make the "canceling" go away is closing the composetor window. but the moment I open it again it comes back.

I really hope someone can help me with this problem

Comment: Without knowing your node setup and settings it will be very hard to determine what the issue is

Comment: stop playback (Alt+A)

Comment: I've been having this issue as well and came to the conclusion that (at least for me) it has something to do with the animation nodes even when playback is stopped. It cripples my ability to render until I delete the animation nodes and have yet to find a work around. .blend linked as example[cancelling loop](https://drive.google.com/open?id=165H610fWhAi_rJYN4_Frab4osbXFnkfe)

Answer (score 1):

In Animation Nodes, Disabling "Always" under Auto-execute fixed this for me.
Same issue as you, in Compositor constant "Canceling.." in the status bar. Viewer was absolutely broken and would not update plus that flickering issue you described. Seems like if AN is set to always try and solve it's nodes, it conflicts with Compositors ability to update.

Frame Changed, Property Changed & Tree Changed seem to be fine to keep active.
Also Viewer nodes (in animation nodes) don't seem to cause issues either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to stop by deleting the viewer node from my node group in the animation nodes add-on. I was using a viewer node to confirm my output was correct when sending some text data. From now on I know just to use it to check and then delete it. Probably has something to do with the viewer node also being used in the compositing tab?